# TYPO3 Error: Table of already deleted custom extension not found

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

i first deactivated and then deleted my custom made extension in the TYPO3 Backend.
When I open a page, where I have another custom TYPO3 extension included, in the browser I get an error code and the following error in my log files:

> {"exception":"Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Mysqli\MysqliException: Table 'my-project.tx_domain_model_my_already_deleted_extension_name' doesn't exist

The weird thing is, the name of the table in the error message is from my already deleted extension.
Still, if I create the table and then run "Analyze Database Structure" it suggests to delete this table from the error message because it seems that it isn't needed.

I also cleared the cache in the BE, deleted all the folders and files in "typo3temp" manually and checked if all the extension files in "typo3conf/ext" are gone, but none of that makes the error disappear.

Has anyone else had the same error? Are there any other caching files which I need to delete that my old extension is completely gone?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are other caches: Maybe PHP OPcache, composer cache. Which TYPO3 did you use and as a composer installation or the older classic way?

Comment: do you have any references to these tables in other extensions? maybe some TCA? sometimes dependencies are not registered in `ext_emconf.php` and `composer.json` and if you remove an extension you have loose ends which run into errors.

Comment: Typo3 v10.4, I installed it without composer.  
Also I don't have any references to any other extension or TCA.

Comment: Just suggestion: download src (if on dev srv) and search for your `tx_domain_model_my_already_deleted_extension_name` string also in cached files, than try realize what includes it. It may be for an instance some TS stored in DB - not only in files.

Comment: Also to keep it working before you'll identify the problem, just create that table in DB w/ required structure.

Comment: thank you for your help so far! Unfortunately I was not able to find "tx_domain_model_my_already_deleted_extension_name" in my downloaded server files, nor anywhere in the DB. @biesior

Comment: Had similar problems with "non-declared" tables, and in most cases that was about cache clearing and/or Apache's restarting.